Trying to build an organizational chart of specific offices
I'm still fairly new to powershell so apologize if this something super basic. We got a request to create a organizational chart that will be exported to a csv and then used for other applications f some of our offices that includes the supervisor of the office, the manager of the office, and finally the VP of the region. I've gotten it to pull the office through manager with this script:
$supervisors = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Title -Like '*supervisor*'" -Properties Office, Manager | Where-Object Office -notlike "*Corporate Office*" | select Office, Name, @{Name="Manager"; Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.manager).name}})


The problem is we need to add one final column with the VPs of each office which is who the managers report to. Additional some of the supervisors of branches report directly to the VP's themselves so they are listed in the manager section so we need that name to carry over to the new column. For reference here is the layout the info is pulling in. I've tried adding all the info to an array and tried -getaduser to pull info from just the manager section. I'm kinda lost at this point and don't know where to go.
Office                  Supervisor             Manager


So the final column would be the manager of the manager or if null, the managers themselves basically?

Pretty much yes, but if the that manager is listed in the manager column then we would just want it to carry over to the that column as well

If I understood correctly, you should use a loop instead of Select-Object, it will be easier to read the code and will avoid querying the same user twice. Adding some comments to help you follow the logic.
$getADUserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(&(title=*supervisor*)(!physicalDeliveryOfficeName=*Corporate Office*))'
    Properties = 'Office', 'Manager'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    $manager = $vp = $null
    try {
        # get the manager's `.Name` and try to get the manager's `Manager`
        $manager = Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties Manager
        # try to get the manager's `Manager` name
        $vp = (Get-ADUser $manager.Manager).Name
    }
    catch {
        # if that failed, fall back to the same value used for `Manager` property
        $vp = $manager.Name
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Office  = $_.Office
        Name    = $_.Name
        Manager = $manager.Name
        VP      = $vp
    }
}


I tried this with updating some of the variables to what we have listed in our AD and it errored out with this
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At line:8 char:27


$manager = Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties Manager



                      ~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser




@Spaff_Wallbridge that error means that some of the users don't have a manager, what should happen in that case ? the updated code will handle that error but the value for manager and vp will be null for some users

Tried the most updated code and the output was just the ldapfiler and properties section

@Spaff_Wallbridge not sure what that means. those are assignments not output. did you check that the $supervisors variable isnt populated?

I'm pasting the script into a blank PS page. I add the @getADUserSplat at the end just to see what how it looks and the output is just the ldapfilter and properties and the code next to them. It looks like it's not doing anything after that
